# LDAP access denied (Error 49 data 5) on win server 2012R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ldap

[image]

This is a fresh installation (windows 2012 R2), I disabled everything related to kerberos, but that did not fix the problem.
All users have this problem, the Credentials are correct.

Bind type: simple

Comment: I notice you have no internet connection, what are you using for a time server? Kerberos and Active Directory authentication is dependent on accurate time stamps.

Comment: It's a Vritual Machine. The time should be the same as the host (configured with same Timezone), But still the error is in the server itself. This is a simple bind, not Kerberos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my copy of windows. I downloaded another iso and that fixed the problem.